# Oneshot Circuit Design Improvement

Tags: circuit-design, timer

Question is related to [my this question here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/691004/one-shot-buzzer).

I want to trigger a buzzer for 500ms to 1sec whenever a switch is opened, answers on that question didn't produce satisfactory results so I came up with a new design myself.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEQ9WI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

While the switch is closed, it charges C1 and keeps Q1 pulled high, when switch is opened, Q1 turns on discharging capacitor to the buzzer,

It consumes very small amount of current (<1mA) and it buzzes for decent time (400-700ms) but when switch is closed, I could faintly hear buzzer which could also sometimes randomly start beeping with higher voltages, buzzer also sounds horrible as it needs higher current, decreasing R2 makes it sound slightly better but decreases time and increases power consumption, how can I improve this design?

I am now open to suggestions of using comparators, operational amplifiers, tl431 or using a different battery.